# Magento - Add custom layout updates for module

Tags: php, magento

I've created my module and it works fine. Now I want to include some custom layout updates so that I can load in the required JS and CSS files for it.

So I've gone in to app/code/community/module/relatedbrand/etc/config.xml and added the following code below the closing `</global>` tag.

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <relatedbrand>
                <file>relatedbrand.xml</file>
            </relatedbrand>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then within app/design/frontend/module/default/layout/relatedbrand.xml I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>

        <action method="addJs"><script>carousel/carousel.min.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</layout>
```

However, when I navigate to the page where the module is active carousel.min.js isn't included. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout is wrong.
It should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default> <!-- you are missing this-->
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>

            <action method="addJs"><script>carousel/carousel.min.js</script></action>
        </reference>
     </default>
</layout>
```

The code above should add the js files to all your pages. If you want only for a specific page, replace `<default>` with the page layout handle.
for example for product page use `<catalog_product_view>`, for customer dashboard use `<customer_account_index>`

Comment: Ahh damn! Thanks a lot Marius, I knew it would be something small. Again you come and make me feel a bit daft ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your file is at correct place

```
skin\frontend\default\default\js
```

may be different if you are using custom theme or package.

and change it like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>

        <action method="addJs"><script>carousel/carousel.min.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Comment: It is said that XML data is invalid.